# Список расширений для установки в Visual Studio Code пуст

Tags: extension, visual-studio-code

Здравствуйте. Я хочу установить расширение ext install debugger-for-chrome в Visual Studio Code. Я настроил подключение к прокси серверу. Но ничего не происходит, список расширений пуст. На отсутствие Интернета редактор не ругается - просто ничего не происходит. Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.